# 12ヶ月の中の複数月の平均を求めるアルゴリズム

Tags: sql, アルゴリズム

お世話になります。

業務で、今度の四月から開始される『働き方改革』の中に、複数月の平均が80時間を超えてはならないと
いうのがあり、それを求めるためのツールをAccessで作成しています。

四月から始まり、三月で終わる一年の期間の中で、二ヶ月以上の連続した組み合わせ(4-5,4-5-6,4-5-6-7～1-2-3,2-3まで)の平均を算出するのですが、数を数えてみると合計で66パターンの組み合わせができてしまいます。これを人数分だけ計算するとなると、かなりの時間がかかると思います。
勿論、一つ一つ行って、一度でも80時間超えがあれば、そこで確認済みにすれば良い話ではあるのですが、これをもっと効率的にやりたいと思っています。

上記のような、『総当たりの平均』を求めるやり方で、もっと効率の良い方法はありますでしょうか？SQLなどでできれば、とてもエレガントだとは思いますが…。SQLの平均の記述が解らないのではなく、コードのようにループさせなくて済む方法です。

強引にコードに直すと、下記のようになると思います。

```
　　　Dim arr(11) As Long　'　ここでは宣言しかしていませんが、既に中身があるものと思ってください。
　　　Dim d0 As Long, d1 As Long, d2 As Long
    Dim val As Double
    Dim flg As Boolean

    flg = False
    For d0 = 0 To 11 - 1
        For d1 = d0 + 1 To 12 - 1
            val = 0#
            For d2 = d0 To d1
                val = val + arr(d2)
                If (val / ((d1 - d0) + 1) > 80) Then
                    flg = True
                    GoTo End_for
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next

End_for:
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 連続時間数は素数の場合だけ調べればよさそうですね。期間2, 3, 5, 7, 11の移動平均を出して80を超えた時をチェックするという形になるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 常に年間の全データを計算する必要は無いのでは？ チェック作業時点あるいは直前の締め月を起点として過去2～6カ月の平均を計算すれば、5回で済むのではないでしょうか。こういう規則は、施行後にリアルタイムに適用・チェックされていれば良いのでは？

Comment: kunifさん、いつもありがとうございます。仰る通りなのですが、今回は『今までの残業時間から求める』という、過去のデータから計算する必要があったため、総当たりを計算する必要がありました。…確かに、考えてみればこれから施行される法律ですから、その時から調査すれば良い話ですよね。今回は『こういった過去実績から計算する必要がある場合には』というケースで考えさせてください。

Comment: orangecatさん、ありがとうございます。ですが、私も無知なのでどうして『期間2, 3, 5, 7, 11の移動平均』だけ算出するだけで良いのかが解りません。この『移動平均』というのは、何か数学かなんかの考え方にあるのでしょうか？

Comment: 移動平均とはデータの過去○日間の平均を計算することです。AccessのSQLでどうやれば早く計算できるのか知らないので回答は書けないのですが、キーワードがあれば検索しやすいだろうと思って出しました。これに基準値とのチェックを組み合わせればよいかと

Comment: 移動平均ならば、PostgreSQLでのこんな説明があります。[移動平均を算出 〜Window関数を使って変動傾向を掴む〜](https://dev.classmethod.jp/etc/sql-moving-average/)　Accessでもこんな記事があるので、使えるのでは？ [Calculate Moving Average - MS ACCESS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49457404/9014308)

Comment: あと、平均を求める前に、80時間以上の記録が存在するか否かを判定しておけば、存在しない場合は処理を省略できるので、作業量は減らせるでしょう。

Comment: > 連続時間数は素数の場合だけ調べればよさそう

(1月から4月までの平均:A14)は(1月と2月の平均:A12)と(3月と4月の平均:A34)の平均なのでA14>80ならばA12>80またはA34>80が言えるからです。同様に、期間が素数でない場合は全て期間が素数の場合のチェックでカバーすることができます。

Comment: ちなみに、開始月の4月についての数字も、複数月(最大6カ月)の時間を計算しなくてはならないと思われますので、用意するデータは前年度11月度からの17カ月分ではないでしょうか？

Comment: kunifさん、ありがとうございます。どうやら(噂程度の信用度ですが)平均の取得は四月からの平均らしいです。その為、初めに平均が必要なるのは五月が終了した六月から、4,5月の二ヶ月の平均からのスタートらしいです。はっきりとは解らないのですが…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

『働き方改革』については、[時間外労働の上限規制の「2~6ヵ月平均で80時間以内」とは？【労働基準法改正 2019】](http://ttps://www.ieyasu.co/media/max_80h-average/)　の記事を参考にしました。

この記事によると、「複数月の平均が80時間を超えてはならない」というのは正確には「2ヵ月ないし6か月平均で80時間以内」ということで、
その意味は、“2ヵ月、3ヵ月、4ヵ月、5ヵ月、6か月のいずれの期間においても、月平均80時間以内にしなければならない”。

そうすると、平均を計算しないといけないパターンは、以下の４５種類
２か月：１１パターン（４月から、５月から、・・・、２月から）
３か月：１０パターン（４月から、５月から、・・・、１月から）
４か月：９パターン（４月から、５月から、・・・、１２月から）
５か月：８パターン（４月から、５月から、・・・、１１月から）
６か月：７パターン（４月から、５月から、・・・、１０月から）

月の時間外労働時間が80時間を超えているかどうかの判断にも計算時間がかかるので、80時間を超えるケースが見つかるまで、全てのパターンを順に計算してみる以下のような愚直なコードのほうが計算時間は短くなると思います。

```
Dim overtime(12) As Double　'　12か月(４月から３月まで）の時間外労働時間の配列（データは事前に入れられていると想定)
Dim numOfMonth as Integer, startMonth as Integer, ov as Integer
Dim val As Double
Dim flg As Boolean

flg = False
For numOfMonth = 2 To 6  '平均をとる月の数を、２から６まで変えて調べる
    For startMonth = 0 to 12-numOfMonth '
        val = 0#
        For ov = startMonth To startMonth + numOfMonth -1
            val = val + overtime(ov)
        Next ov
        If ((val / numOfMonth) > 80) Then '月平均時間外労働時間が80時間超えか？
            flg = True
            GoTo End_for
        End If
    Next startMonth
Next numOfMonth

End_for:
  ' flagの値に基づいて、結果を表示する
```

Comment: 皆様、ありがとうございます。気が付かない間にたくさんのコメントや回答を頂き、本当に感謝しております。複数月の平均が六か月間までで良いというのは私の見落としでした。申し訳ありません。これらの点を踏まえ、更によい解決方法を探ってみたいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

(面白そうなんで考えてみました。回答として妥当では無いと思うのですが、コメント欄には書ききれなそうだったので…他の方がこんな問題に対してどういうふうに考えられるのか興味あります。)

---

- 連続する2ヶ月の平均が80時間超ならば、少なくともどちらかが80時間超

  - (裏)連続する2ヶ月の平均が80時間以下ならば、少なくともどちらかが80時間以下

と

- 連続する3ヶ月(m1,m2,m3)平均が80時間超で、かつ、その期間に含まれる連続する2ヶ月平均(※組み合わせは(m1,m2),(m2,m3)の2パターン)が全て80時間以下なら、端の月(期間の開始月m1、終了月m3、の2月)のいずれも80時間超

は正しそうで、ここから

- 連続するnヶ月平均が80時間超で、かつ、その期間に含まれる連続するn-1ヶ月平均が全て(※組み合わせは2パターン)80時間以下なら、端の月のいずれも80時間超

も言えそうな気がするので

1. 80時間超の月と前月との2ヶ月平均
2. 80時間超の月と翌月との2ヶ月平均
3. 80時間超の月と、翌直近の80時間超の月との間の平均

を調べれば良さそうに思われます。

単月での80時間超は許容される、というのが3.以外に1.,2.も調べないといけないのに繋がっているのかな、と。

Answer (score 0):

Fumu 7さんの回答ですが

> そうすると、平均を計算しないといけないパターンは、以下の４５種類
>   ２か月：１１パターン（４月から、５月から、・・・、２月から）
>   ３か月：１０パターン（４月から、５月から、・・・、１月から）
>   ４か月：９パターン（４月から、５月から、・・・、１２月から）
>   ５か月：８パターン（４月から、５月から、・・・、１１月から）
>   ６か月：７パターン（４月から、５月から、・・・、１０月から）

もう少し簡略化できます。

４か月パターンですが１例を挙げると4-7で平均80時間を超える場合、平均の原理から4-5と6-7のどちらかが80時間を超えることになります。4-5も6-7も２か月パターンで検査済みですから、４か月パターンをチェックする必要はありません。同様に５か月、６か月も省略可能です。

- ２か月： 4-5, 5-6, 6-7, 7-8, 8-9, 9-10, 10-11, 11-12, 12-1, 1-2, 2-3
- ３か月： 4-6, 5-7, 6-8, 7-9, 8-10, 9-11, 10-12, 11-1, 12-2, 1-3

の計２１パターンの検査で済みます。
考え方次第ですが、ここまで絞り込めたのであれば、もう愚直にハードコーディングされるのも１つの手です。

---

yukihaneさんの考え方はここから更に数学的に候補を減らしたものです。ただし「80時間超の月」を探す処理が必要になっていますのでSQLでの記述は難しくなります。

Answer (score 0):

もし、 CTE が使える DB につながっているのであれば、以下のようにすると、 66 パターンを sql 上で一発で取得できたりします。(下記は、 mysql の場合)

```
-- base は、適宜、 DB からの月次の集計結果クエリに置き換える
with recursive base as (
  select 4 as `month`, 74 as hours
  union all
  select 5, 75
  union all
  select 6, 76
  union all
  select 7, 77
  union all
  select 8, 78
  union all
  select 9, 79
  union all
  select 10, 80
  union all
  select 11, 81
  union all
  select 12, 82
  union all
  select 1, 83
  union all
  select 2, 84
  union all
  select 3, 85
), unioned as (
    select CAST(`month` as CHAR(255)) as months, `month` as last_month, 1 as num_months, hours * 1.0 as hours from base
  union all
    select concat(months, '-', `month`), `month` as last_month, num_months + 1, (unioned.hours * num_months + base.hours) * 1.0 / (num_months + 1)
    from unioned inner join base on (unioned.last_month) % 12 + 1 = base.`month`
    where unioned.last_month <> 3
)
select * from unioned
where num_months > 1;
```

実行結果

```
+----------------------------+------------+------------+-------+
| months                     | last_month | num_months | hours |
+----------------------------+------------+------------+-------+
| 4-5                        |          5 |          2 |  74.5 |
| 5-6                        |          6 |          2 |  75.5 |
| 6-7                        |          7 |          2 |  76.5 |
| 7-8                        |          8 |          2 |  77.5 |
| 8-9                        |          9 |          2 |  78.5 |
| 9-10                       |         10 |          2 |  79.5 |
| 10-11                      |         11 |          2 |  80.5 |
| 11-12                      |         12 |          2 |  81.5 |
| 12-1                       |          1 |          2 |  82.5 |
| 1-2                        |          2 |          2 |  83.5 |
| 2-3                        |          3 |          2 |  84.5 |
| 4-5-6                      |          6 |          3 |  75.0 |
| 5-6-7                      |          7 |          3 |  76.0 |
| 6-7-8                      |          8 |          3 |  77.0 |
| 7-8-9                      |          9 |          3 |  78.0 |
| 8-9-10                     |         10 |          3 |  79.0 |
| 9-10-11                    |         11 |          3 |  80.0 |
| 10-11-12                   |         12 |          3 |  81.0 |
| 11-12-1                    |          1 |          3 |  82.0 |
| 12-1-2                     |          2 |          3 |  83.0 |
| 1-2-3                      |          3 |          3 |  84.0 |
| 4-5-6-7                    |          7 |          4 |  75.5 |
| 5-6-7-8                    |          8 |          4 |  76.5 |
| 6-7-8-9                    |          9 |          4 |  77.5 |
| 7-8-9-10                   |         10 |          4 |  78.5 |
| 8-9-10-11                  |         11 |          4 |  79.5 |
| 9-10-11-12                 |         12 |          4 |  80.5 |
| 10-11-12-1                 |          1 |          4 |  81.5 |
| 11-12-1-2                  |          2 |          4 |  82.5 |
| 12-1-2-3                   |          3 |          4 |  83.5 |
| 4-5-6-7-8                  |          8 |          5 |  76.0 |
| 5-6-7-8-9                  |          9 |          5 |  77.0 |
| 6-7-8-9-10                 |         10 |          5 |  78.0 |
| 7-8-9-10-11                |         11 |          5 |  79.0 |
| 8-9-10-11-12               |         12 |          5 |  80.0 |
| 9-10-11-12-1               |          1 |          5 |  81.0 |
| 10-11-12-1-2               |          2 |          5 |  82.0 |
| 11-12-1-2-3                |          3 |          5 |  83.0 |
| 4-5-6-7-8-9                |          9 |          6 |  76.5 |
| 5-6-7-8-9-10               |         10 |          6 |  77.5 |
| 6-7-8-9-10-11              |         11 |          6 |  78.5 |
| 7-8-9-10-11-12             |         12 |          6 |  79.5 |
| 8-9-10-11-12-1             |          1 |          6 |  80.5 |
| 9-10-11-12-1-2             |          2 |          6 |  81.5 |
| 10-11-12-1-2-3             |          3 |          6 |  82.5 |
| 4-5-6-7-8-9-10             |         10 |          7 |  77.0 |
| 5-6-7-8-9-10-11            |         11 |          7 |  78.0 |
| 6-7-8-9-10-11-12           |         12 |          7 |  79.0 |
| 7-8-9-10-11-12-1           |          1 |          7 |  80.0 |
| 8-9-10-11-12-1-2           |          2 |          7 |  81.0 |
| 9-10-11-12-1-2-3           |          3 |          7 |  82.0 |
| 4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11          |         11 |          8 |  77.5 |
| 5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12         |         12 |          8 |  78.5 |
| 6-7-8-9-10-11-12-1         |          1 |          8 |  79.5 |
| 7-8-9-10-11-12-1-2         |          2 |          8 |  80.5 |
| 8-9-10-11-12-1-2-3         |          3 |          8 |  81.5 |
| 4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12       |         12 |          9 |  78.0 |
| 5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-1       |          1 |          9 |  79.0 |
| 6-7-8-9-10-11-12-1-2       |          2 |          9 |  80.0 |
| 7-8-9-10-11-12-1-2-3       |          3 |          9 |  81.0 |
| 4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-1     |          1 |         10 |  78.5 |
| 5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-1-2     |          2 |         10 |  79.5 |
| 6-7-8-9-10-11-12-1-2-3     |          3 |         10 |  80.5 |
| 4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-1-2   |          2 |         11 |  79.0 |
| 5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-1-2-3   |          3 |         11 |  80.0 |
| 4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-1-2-3 |          3 |         12 |  79.5 |
+----------------------------+------------+------------+-------+
66 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLで総当たりを求めると考えると
再帰CTEの使えないACCESSでやるのであれば、素直に66通りの組み合わせテーブルを作るのが良いんじゃないでしょうか

仮に組み合わせテーブルを
FromTo(from Integer,to integer)として
(1,2)
(1,3)
...
(1,12)
(2,3)
...
(2,12)
(11,12)
の66レコードを用意し
あとは

```
SELECT 
FromTo.from, 
FromTo.to, 
(select avg(時間) from クエリ1 where 月番号>= FromTo.from and 月番号<=FromTo.to) AS 平均時間
FROM 
FromTo;
```

のようなクエリで取れます

月番号は年度ごとに4月～翌3月を1～12になるように調整している前提です
例えばこんなクエリ

```
SELECT 
IIf(Month(年月)<4,Year(年月)-1,Year(年月)) AS 年度, 
IIf(Month(年月)<4,Month(年月)+9,Month(年月)-3) AS 月番号, 
テーブル1.時間
FROM 
テーブル1
WHERE 
(((IIf(Month(年月)<4,Year(年月)-1,Year(年月)))=2018));
```

Answer (score 0):

- パターンが有限
- 年度単位で、人別に残業時間を集計する必要がありそう

という点を踏まえると、各パターンを計算するSQLを愚直に書き、結果をUNIONで結合するのが簡単かな、思いました。

以下のような感じを考えています。

```sql
-- テスト用の仮テーブル
CREATE TABLE test (
    name varchar 
    ,year  int
    ,month int
    ,hour float);

-- テスト用データの準備    
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('A', 2019, 4,  60.0)
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('A', 2019, 5,  30.0)
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('A', 2019, 6,  20.0)
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('A', 2019, 7,  40.0)
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('A', 2019, 8,  80.0)
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('A', 2019, 9,  70.4)
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('A', 2019, 10, 100.4)
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('A', 2019, 11, 20.4)
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('A', 2019, 12, 30.4)
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('A', 2019, 1,  30.4)
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('A', 2019, 2,  10.4)
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('A', 2019, 3,  20.4)
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('B', 2019, 4,  10.4)
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('B', 2019, 5,  30.4)
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('B', 2019, 6,  60.4)
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('B', 2019, 7,  10.4)
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('B', 2019, 8,  30.4)
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('B', 2019, 9,  60.4)
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('B', 2019, 10, 10.4)
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('B', 2019, 11, 30.4)
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('B', 2019, 12, 60.4)
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('B', 2019, 1,  10.4)
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('B', 2019, 2,  30.4)
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('B', 2019, 3,  60.4)

-- パターン別に計算してUNION
SELECT name, year, '4-5' AS 'target', avg(hour) AS 'avg_hour' FROM test WHERE month In (4, 5) GROUP BY year, name
union
SELECT name, year, '5-6' AS 'target', avg(hour) AS 'avg_hour' FROM test WHERE month In (5, 6) GROUP BY year, name
union
(以下略)
```

80時間超過を抽出したければ、`HAVING avg(hour) > 80`を　各パターンのクエリの最後に加える手もあります。

Answer (score 0):

皆さん、ありがとうございます。
皆さんのヒントを元に、自分なりに考えてみた『自己レス』です。

もっと良い方法があると思いますので、指摘などしていただければ幸いです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

こんなテーブルを作成しました。m0からm11には、四月から始まり、翌年三月までの
残業時間が入っている者とします。

その結果、下記のコードを実行しました。

```
Private Sub calcTotalAverage()
    Dim d0 As Long, d1 As Long, d2 As Long
    Dim condition As String
    Dim dtSt As Date

    dtSt = #2018/04/01#

   '   6か月間総当たり
    For d0 = 0 To 11 - 1
        For d1 = d0 + 1 To 12 - 1

　　　　　　　　　'　最長六ヶ月のため
            If ((d1 - d0) > 6) Then
                Exit For
            End If

            SQL = "UPDATE T_overtime SET [最大平均時間] = "

            condition = "("
            For d2 = d0 To d1
                condition = condition & "m" & d2 & " + "
            Next
            condition = condition & "0) / " & (d1 - d0 + 1)
            SQL = SQL & condition & ",[最大平均開始月] = '" & Format(DateAdd("m", d0, dtSt), "m月") & "',[最大平均終了月] = '" & Format(DateAdd("m", d1, dtSt), "m月") & "' WHERE [最大平均時間] < " & condition

            CurrentDb.Execute (SQL)
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

最終的に、平均の最大値が80を超えているかどうかを見るので、ひとまず愚直に全員の最大の平均時間を算出しました。その上で、『最大平均時間』が80を超えているかどうかを見れば良いかと。

ここまでは単純に総当たりですが、皆様から教えていただいた『素数の平均』の考え方が入れば、もっと
効率よくなるのではないかと思うのですが、いかがでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。